# After update to MySQL 8 a reliable stored procedure gives errors after applying change

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, upgrade

A stored procedure developed some years ago, which employs many views to update a newly created table, is giving errors since upgrading to MYSQL 8. I can run the final View contained in the procedure, which calls all the others and it runs fine. But if I run the procedure it gives a divide by zero error on the first update query. I can't find anything wrong elsewhere. I can repeat the problem by taking a routine that works, adding a blank like so that there's a change and clicking 'accept'. Then the same routine gives the errors. The errors are:Error Code: 1264. Out of range value for column '....' at row 1, which is a decimal (5,2) and if I increase to decimal (6,2) I get Error Code: 1365. Division by 0.
Help!

Comment: Please share more infomation, like the defintioon of that stored procedure and the **exact** erorr message

Comment: The stored procedure is huge, does lots of arithmetic and updates a table with the results.I believe the only scope for divide by zero errors is when nulls occur, which were all caught with If() statements. These are the exact error messages. As I say, the procedure has worked fine for years. But thanks for looking Nico.

Comment: Just to add to the mystery, if I run all the query elements of the stored routine everything works fine. It's only when the final table is updated with new info that the errors show up.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to different SQL modes between server setups. MySQL has SQL modes `ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO` and strict mode, which determine if an error is raised when by zero happens or if the result will be determined to be `NULL`.

Your original procedures were written (procedures keep their modes) when the settings were different from your current one. When you change the code, the procedure get the current mode.

Comment: Thanks slaakso - didn't know that procedures keep their modes.

Comment: Storing the mode with the procedure ensures that the procedures run in the mode that they were designed to run. Modes may change (users change the server mode, mode in the connection may change, different MySQL versions have different modes), so storing the mode with the procedure ensures the old code continues to run.

Comment: Quick update: I added 'SET GLOBAL sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'' to my broken routine and it works fine!
Thanks again slaakso.

Comment: Instead of reverting back to older sql_mode, you might want to consider fixing the procedure instead. Check for the part that causes the Division by 0 and correct that one.

Comment: Yes, that's my next task. Thanks again slaakso.